# Boids avoid collision?

Tags: particles, collision

Im trying to make a flock of birds in a massive cage using boids.
But they keep flying through the walls.
How do I tell them to stay in the cage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Create your cage, I have used a box
2. Select your box and enable *Edit Mode* (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
3. Keep the box selected and go to *Mesh > Normals > Flip Normals*
4. Then go to the Physics tab, and enable the Collision modifier

Now your boids should interact with the cage. Hope it helps.

[image: Example]